# Getting all possible couple permutations of a list's elements in Python

Tags: python, list, combinations, permutation

If I have a Python list:

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3]
```

And would like to get all possible ways of "adding" these items **two at a time**, like so:

The desired output:

- (1 + 2) + 3
- 1 + (2 + 3)
- (1 + 3) + 2
- 1 + (3 + 2)  etc...

For longer lists like:

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

- 1 + (2 + 3) + (4 + 5)
- (1 + 2) + 3 + (4 + 5)
- (1 + 2) + (3 + 4) + 5

The items need to be "added" two at a time

What is the most efficient way to do this that would also work with with longer lists?

I tried using `itertools` combinations and permutations but couldn't figure out how to reach the desired result.

```py
stuff = [1, 2, 3]

for per in itertools.permutations(stuff):
    print(per)
```

This returned all the possible permutations of the elements, but I'm stuck as to how I should split them into all combinations of couples while taking into consideration the odd elements out, especially in longer lists.

Comment: So what *did* you try from `itertools`? You should show this.

Comment: So, for longer lists, say `[1,2,3,4,5]` do you want to show: `(1+2)+3+4+5` and `(1+2)+(3+4)+5` etc?

Comment: So it looks like you need to apply all the permuations of pairs to each `per in permutations(stuff):` Perhaps for a given `len(stuff)` you should work out what the permutations of pairs are. eg. `2,2,1`,  `2,1,2`, `1,2,2`.

Comment: An avenue to explore might be a recursive algorithm, choosing one permutation from the list at a time and removing it and then permuting what's left, all the way down to a list of length 1 or 2 as the base case.

Comment: Also, then what about when `len(stuff)` is even? Do you only want `2,2,2...`?